# How do I use Clipboard.js dynamically with background color?

Tags: javascript, jquery, clipboard

I have a button:

```
<button class="badge" style="background-color: #ff3333;" data-clipboard-target="#badge">RED</button>
```

that I'd like to copy the color of using Clipboard.js. I understand that I can do this manually with data-clipboard-target but I was hoping to trigger the event dynamically using something like [their sample code](https://clipboardjs.com):

```
new ClipboardJS('.btn', {
text: function(trigger) {
    return trigger.getAttribute('aria-label');
}};
```

I tried using about 100 variants of:

```
 new ClipboardJS(".badge", {
  text: function(trigger) {
    return $(trigger).closest(".badge").element.style.backgroundColor(); 
  }
});
```

but I keep getting the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined`.

I realize that I can just use data-clipboard-target and do this manually but I was hoping figure out why the targeting is off. Thanks

Comment: Try `console.log($(trigger).closest(".badge").element)` and see why there's no `style` property. I think you actually want `$(trigger).closest(".badge").css('background-color');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the `data-clipboard-text` and then return the text you want copied in the `text function`. Also you can use `trigger.style.backgroundColor` to get the background color.

```js
new ClipboardJS(".badge", {
  text: function(trigger) {
    var result = trigger.style.backgroundColor
    return console.log(result) || result
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/clipboard@2/dist/clipboard.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="badge" style="background-color: #ff3333;" data-clipboard-text="">RED</button>
```

Comment: That's great. That "trigger.style.backgroundColor" part was very unclear to me. Ha, now I see that it returns rgb colors not hex though, so on to the next problem.